# Trustsec security

Tags: network, network-access-control

I am researching a bit on Cisco's Trustsec technology.  My understanding is that it places a tag on packets based on machine and/or user ID.  Trustsec can then use that tag as it traverses the network to enforce policy based on the tag information.

So my initial thought is that it should work fine as long as it is in a controlled network but once it enters an uncontrolled network it seems that the tag could be edited or even counterfeited enroute.

Does anyone have a good idea of how this works and whether end to end control is needed to maintain integrity of the tags?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: yes, tags only work within the network

Comment: Thank you for the response, that was my thinking as well, it seems like a cheap way to define security but they are marketing it as extremely high security, I was not seeing it, so I thought  I better ask in case there is something I was missing.